# Virtual Destructor needed when using Cloaking pattern?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor, cloaking

If I have the following 3 classes to hide the data type and store information,
do I need a virtual destructor? I was led to believe no, but now I am not sure.
I would rather not include it if possible for preformance reasons.  Classes stripped down for example sake.

```
#include <memory>

class DarkHideInterface
{
  public:
  bool test;

};


template <typename T>
class DarkHideInterfaceImpl : public DarkHideInterface
{
  public:
  DarkHideInterfaceImpl (const T& t )  : _t(t) {}

  private: 
  T _t; 
};


class DarkHide
{
  public:
  template <class T> DarkHide (const T& t) : p_(new DarkHideInterfaceImpl<T>(t) ) { } 

  private:
  std::auto_ptr<DarkHideInterface> p_; 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `auto_ptr`, I think you need the virtual destructor, since the `delete` will happen polymorphically - in other words, internally `auto_ptr` will ultimately call `delete` on the stored `DarkHideInterface*`. If `DarkHideInterface` doesn't have a virtual destructor and the pointer points to a `DarkHideInterfaceImpl` instance, then you get undefined behaviour.

Note that you wouldn't need a virtual destructor with `shared_ptr` as far as I know, because that remembers the type of the pointer with which it was constructed and calls `delete` on that pointer directly (search for 'virtual destructor' here to see what I mean: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: thanks, this makes sense to me. i was wondering if unique_ptr in the new 0x standard would work the same way.